# find the entire string based on only the substring from a string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.6

This might be a repetitive question, after searching for a bit, I couldn't find an answer and thus I am posting the question.
How do I find the entire string based on only the substring from a string?

```
import re

test = 'INFO: 106.00s - SearchDriver: GET CThru=27.027 OThru=25.566 CErr=0.000 CResp=0.013 OResp=0.011 CSD=0.015 OSD=0.010 C90%Resp=0.025 O90%Resp=0.025'
```

To get the value of `CThru=27.027`, I'm trying to do this.

```
re.findall("CThru=*", test)
```

but it returns only

```
['CThru=']
```

Comment: You misunderstood how `*` works. This is regex, not glob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` *quantifier* is always applied to the thing it is placed after; `<regex thing>*` means that `<regex thing>` should be matched zero or more times.

For your attempt, `<regex thing>` is the `=` character, so `=*` means: zero or more equals characters. And indeed, `'CThru='` contains one such equal character, and no more. The `*` won't match anything else! This differs from [*glob* syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)), commonly used when listing files, where *just* the `*` character, on its own, is used to match *zero or more filename characters*. Regular expressions are not glob patterns.

If you wanted to get the value *following* the `=` character, you need to put in a pattern (a regex thing) to match *characters in the value text*. Since values are always characters that are *not* spaces (a space separates the key=value pairs), you could use the `[^ ]` set to say *not a space* and add `+` to that to make sure there is at least one character. `[^...]` is a *negative set*, a regex 'thing' that'll match any character in the text that is *not* in the set, so `[^ ]` matches any character that is not a space. The `+` quantifier means *one* or more characters, so we want 1 or more characters that are not spaces. `*` and `+` are *greedy*, meaning that the regex matcher will use as many characters as it can take to satisfy that pattern.

If you put `(...)` parentheses around that part, you tell the regex engine to capture that part and put it in a group, and `re.findall()` will return everything in group 1 if there is just that group. So *just the values* after `CThru=` is returned:

```
re.findall("CThru=([^ ]+)", test)
```

This will return *any kind of text that is not spaces*, as a list:

```
>>> import re
>>> test = 'INFO: 106.00s - SearchDriver: GET CThru=27.027 OThru=25.566 CErr=0.000 CResp=0.013 OResp=0.011 CSD=0.015 OSD=0.010 C90%Resp=0.025 O90%Resp=0.025'
>>> re.findall("CThru=([^ ]+)", test)
['27.027']
```

If there is only ever going to be *one* such key-value pair, you may as well use `re.search()`, and ask for group 1 if that gives you a result that is not `None`:

```
match = re.search("CThru=([^ ]+)", test)
if match:
    value = match.group(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I guess that was needed!

Answer (score 0):

The asterisk on the end is making the string `CThru=` greedy (0 or more matches), but it doesn't search for anything after it.

Something along the lines of `re.findall("CThru=\d*\.\d*", test)` should work, as long as `CThru=` is always followed by a float and then a space.

Answer (score 0):

```
re.findall("CThru=[^\s]*", test)
```

works well.

You need something before the *.

```
re.findall("CThru=.*", test)
```

will catch from CThru to then end of the string, for example.